# Difference between calculating a t-statistic manually and with R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I am following a MOOC course on statistical analysis. The course goes through theoretical and practical exercises in R. One of these exercises consists in the following:

I have a database called "nc", presenting a list of 1000 births in North Carolina. Within this database there are two variables: weight (numerical) and habit (categorical, with 2 levels = (1) nonsmokers, (2) smokers).

We want to understand if children's weights may be correlated with their mothers' smoking habits. To do this, we calculate a t-statistic between the weight means of the two groups (nonsmokers, smokers). Following the summary for the data:

```
nc %>% group_by(habit) %>% summarize(mean(weight), sd(weight), n())
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  habit     `mean(weight)` `sd(weight)` `n()`
  <fct>              <dbl>        <dbl> <int>
1 nonsmoker           7.14         1.52   873
2 smoker              6.83         1.39   126
3 NA                  3.63        NA        1
```

to calculate the t-statistic, the teacher used the method inference(), as the following:

```
inference(weight, habit, nc, "ht", "mean", method = "theoretical", alternative = "twosided")
```

which provided a t-statistic of 2.359.

```
Response variable: numerical
Explanatory variable: categorical (2 levels) 
n_nonsmoker = 873, y_bar_nonsmoker = 7.1443, s_nonsmoker = 1.5187
n_smoker = 126, y_bar_smoker = 6.8287, s_smoker = 1.3862
H0: mu_nonsmoker =  mu_smoker
HA: mu_nonsmoker != mu_smoker
t = 2.359, df = 125
p_value = 0.0199
```

I tried to manually calculate the t-statistic through the following calculation:

```
t-statistic = (mean_nonsmoker - mean-smoker)/sqrt(sd_nonsmoker**2/n_nonsmoker + sd_smoker**2/n_smoker)
t-statistic = (7.14 - 6.83)/sqrt(1.52**2/873 + 1.39**2/126)
```

but I obtained a t-statistic of 2.312. Why are the two t-statistic different? Does the software use a different calculation?

Comment: What is the meaning of MOOC?

Comment: @sextusempiricus "massive online open course". eg a course from Coursera or similar

Comment: @TakeMeToTheMoon I suggest that you use the full description in the text. Why use the abbreviation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd put my money on this being a small rounding error. Using more precise values from the second table of values

```
(7.1443 - 6.8287)/sqrt((1.5187**2)/873 + (1.3862**2)/126)
```

returns `2.359407` as the answer.

Comment: Wow, that's great. A short question: how could you change the details of the summarize() function?

Comment: Rather than getting `summarise()` to print more significant figures, you would be better off programmatically extracting values. In the `tidyverse` this frequently done via the `filter()` command. You can also use `$` and indexing `[,]` in base R to extract values. I'll stop here though as programming is not the focus of this site.

Comment: @takemetothemoon Why at all do you use the output of `summarize()`? You can directly write the formulas with `mean` and `sd`, or, if you find that more legible, assign the result of `mean` and `sd` to variables and use these subsequently.

Comment: @cdalitz, you are very right. I didn't think about it. Thanks for the advice